# SQLite: Is there any way to assign an Alias to the "Where" clause and not have to repeat it many times?

Tags: sqlite

I have the following table structure:

Table: Table1

Columns:  Entry, Tag1, Tag2, Tag3, Tag4.

(Entry is the row number, i.e. 1, 2, 3, etc.)

If I want to combine all tags into 1 in a single query, I'd do the following:

```
Select Tag1 FROM Table1 
UNION ALL 
Select Tag2 FROM Table1 
UNION ALL 
Select Tag3 FROM Table1 
UNION ALL 
Select Tag4 FROM Table1;
```

But let's say I want to do the above query but only on the entries where Entry is between 100 and 200, I'd use the following code:

```
Select Tag1 FROM Table1 
  WHERE Entry >= 100 AND Entry <= 200 
UNION ALL 
Select Tag2 FROM Table1  
  WHERE Entry >= 100 AND Entry <= 200 
UNION ALL 
Select Tag3 FROM Table1  
  WHERE Entry >= 100 AND Entry <= 200 
UNION ALL 
Select Tag4 FROM Table1 
  WHERE Entry >= 100 AND Entry <= 200;
```

Is there any way I can simply the second query without repeating "WHERE Entry >= 100 AND Entry <= 200" so many times?  In other words, if I had to do the same sort of operation but had 100 columns of tags that I need to combine into a single column and has to be between 2 distinct entries in a table, is it possible to shorten the query significantly?

Comment: no, as it is supposed that you have normalized db structure and do not use `union` often, max is 1-2 times per query

Comment: Your schema isn't normalized. Remove the TagN columns and create a table `Tags (EntryID REFERENCES Table1.rowid, Tag)` instead. Use `JOIN`s to get the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can factor the WHERE clause out using a sub-select:

```
SELECT Tag FROM (
  SELECT Entry, Tag1 AS Tag FROM Table1 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT Entry, Tag2 AS Tag FROM Table1  
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT Entry, Tag3 AS Tag FROM Table1  
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT Entry, Tag4 AS Tag FROM Table1 
)
WHERE Entry >= 100 AND Entry <= 200;
```

Some SQL engines will apply the WHERE clause back into each query when constructing the query plan, but SQLite is not (currently) one of them, so there will be an efficiency cost for writing the query this way.

Comment: I had expected that it could, but the extra scan step in the query plan, as well as the use of a temp b-tree made me think otherwise. However, it does look like that query should meet the conditions to allow flattening.